# Recursion in C: I think the issue is in the second if in fFunc

Tags: c, recursion

So I have spent the last two days trying to debug my code but I can't find where my logic is failing (obviously it is.) It's my first time using recursion. So my fFunc should be as follows : 
*Given a positive integer n, let Fn(i) be defined as follows:*

if i < n then:
Fn(i) = i

if i ≥ n then:
Fn(i) = Σn/j=1 (−1)j+1*j*Fn(i − j)

i and n are scanned in at the start. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int sum = 0, j=0;

int power(int num, int exponent) {

    int powers=1;

    while (exponent>0) {
        powers=powers*num;
        exponent--;
    }
    return powers;
}

int fFunc(int i, int n) {

    if(i<n){
            sum =+ i;
    }
    if(i>=n){
        for(int j=1; j<=n; j++){

            sum +=(power(-1,j+1))*j*fFunc(i-j, n);
        } 
        return sum;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n, i;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &i);

    printf("%d\n", fFunc(i, n));
    return 0;
 }
```

Here are some example inputs and outputs. Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong? I appreciate any pointers, ideas or even criticism. I just wanna learn from my mistakes :)
Example 1:
input:
3 5
output:
5
Example 2:
input:
4 6
output:
-5
Example 3:
input:
8 6
output:
6

Comment: `sum =+` should be `sum +=`

Comment: Don't write two `if` statement with opposite conditions, use `if` followed by `else`.

Comment: `sum` should be a local variable, not a global variable.

Comment: If unsure if you were smart, do not try to be it, as chances are good you shot yourself in the foot. If you want to add to a specific variable you can very well write `s = s + ...`. You did it safely here as well for the `*` operator. `powers=powers*num;`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have changed the code. It was a typo from copying it here, but it unfortunately isnt the problem I'm having with my code. Any other ideas?

Comment: You say "here are some example inputs and outputs", but there are no examples.  Just for your amusement, once upon a very, very long time ago (before I learned to program in C), the compound assignment operators were specified `=+`, `=/` etc., and back in those days, there wasn't a unary `+` operator either.  This design mistake was changed to the (slightly) more modern `+=` operators etc before 1978 — it was already old news in '78.

Comment: If you make `sum` into a local variable in `fFunc()` (as you should), you must also remember to initialize it to `0`.  You don't use your global variable `j`; you have a perfectly good local variable `j` inside the function.  Avoid global variables.  They're sometimes beneficial, but (a simple rule of thumb) if they're a single letter name, that's wrong.  Global variables should have a more-or-less meaningful name.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! My only issue, as ponted out by Jonathan and Barmar was that sum was a global variable. It's always the simple things that get you in the end, isnt it. I know I won't be making these mistakes again!

Comment: You could very well post an answer to your own question, mark this as the accepted answer, and though were not in the need to "spoil" your question's title ... ;-)

Comment: Marking an answer to a question as accepted let's SO mark the question as "*SOLVED*". You can do so by clicking the answer 's exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I got from your problem: global variable removed and as you have only a power of -1, I optimized the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_power(int exponent) {

    if(exponent % 2 == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

int fFunc(int i, int n) {

    if(i < n){
        return i;
    }
    else{
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            sum += my_power(j + 1) * j * fFunc(i-j, n);
        }

        return sum;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Input i: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    printf("%d\n", fFunc(i, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of that! Its much neater like that, nice catch! I did optimise it by implementing memorization for the recursion, it sped up the program an awful lot!